# How to Display Header with length Greater then 40 CHAR In SALV?

Tags: excel, abap, alv

I would like to know is there any way to set Header with 60 char in SALV? Since there is a CHAR limit of 40 when I try using `SET_LONG_TEXT` method.  I am using this SALV to both display and download it as an excel too.

My Prod Code looks like this below.

```
        TRY.
        " Call SALV Factory Method
        cl_salv_table=>factory(
             EXPORTING
               list_display = abap_false
             IMPORTING
               r_salv_table = DATA(lo_salv)
             CHANGING
               t_table      = <fs_global_factor_data> ).


        DATA(lo_columns) = lo_salv->get_columns( ).
        lo_columns->set_optimize(  ).

        DATA(lo_col_ref) = lo_columns->get( ).

        " Get the Field Description in the table
        lr_strucdesc ?= cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_data( ls_struct ).
        /stl/cl_gf_validations=>at_gf_table_struct = lr_strucdesc->get_ddic_field_list( ).
```

Here, I am replacing the long text with my own texts with a length of 60 Char from the `AT_FIELD_HEADER` table.

```
       " Remove Short and Medium texts and Replace long texts from AT_FIELD_HEADER Table             
        LOOP AT lo_col_ref ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_col_ref>).
          <fs_col_ref>-r_column->set_short_text( space ).
          <fs_col_ref>-r_column->set_medium_text( space ).
          <fs_col_ref>-r_column->set_fixed_header_text( lc_char_l ) .
          <fs_col_ref>-r_column->set_long_text( SWITCH #( <fs_col_ref>-columnname+0(5) WHEN /stl/cl_gf_validations=>ac_desc_field_prefix THEN /stl/cl_gf_validations=>ac_fd_description
                                                            ELSE CONV #( LET line = VALUE /stl/cl_gf_validations=>ty_field_header( /stl/cl_gf_validations=>at_field_header[ fieldname = <fs_col_ref>-columnname ] OPTIONAL )
                                                                            IN COND #( WHEN line-title IS NOT INITIAL THEN line-title ELSE line-description )
                                                              ) ) ).

        ENDLOOP.

        DATA(lv_xml_type) = if_salv_bs_xml=>c_type_xlsx.
        DATA(lv_data_in_xstring)      = lo_salv->to_xml( xml_type = lv_xml_type ).

      CATCH cx_root.
        MESSAGE e033(/stl/bw_gf_msg).
    ENDTRY.

    " Convert XSTRING TO BIN
    CALL FUNCTION 'SCMS_XSTRING_TO_BINARY'
      EXPORTING
        buffer        = lv_data_in_xstring
      IMPORTING
        output_length = lv_file_size
      TABLES
        binary_tab    = lt_data_in_bin.
```

Here, `GUI_DOWNLOAD` is used to download it as an excel file.

```
    " Download the Excel
    cl_gui_frontend_services=>gui_download(
      EXPORTING
        bin_filesize              = lv_file_size
        filename                  =  lv_fullpath
        filetype                  = lc_filetype_bin
      CHANGING
        data_tab                  =  lt_data_in_bin
      EXCEPTIONS
        file_write_error          = 1
        no_batch                  = 2
        gui_refuse_filetransfer   = 3
        invalid_type              = 4
        no_authority              = 5
        unknown_error             = 6
        header_not_allowed        = 7
        separator_not_allowed     = 8
        filesize_not_allowed      = 9
        header_too_long           = 10
        dp_error_create           = 11
        dp_error_send             = 12
        dp_error_write            = 13
        unknown_dp_error          = 14
        access_denied             = 15
        dp_out_of_memory          = 16
        disk_full                 = 17
        dp_timeout                = 18
        file_not_found            = 19
        dataprovider_exception    = 20
        control_flush_error       = 21
        not_supported_by_gui      = 22
        error_no_gui              = 23
        OTHERS                    = 24
    ).
    IF sy-subrc <> 0.
      MESSAGE ID sy-msgid TYPE sy-msgty NUMBER sy-msgno
                 WITH sy-msgv1 sy-msgv2 sy-msgv3 sy-msgv4.
    ENDIF.
```

Also, I am using the same piece of code to display the SALV where header gets truncated to 40 char.

Comment: `cl_salv_table` can set column heading texts with a maximum of 40 characters. You could use [abap2xlsx](https://github.com/sapmentors/abap2xlsx) to update the Excel file after `to_xml` and before `gui_download`.

Comment: @SandraRossi,  But the business didn't give permission to install abap2xlsx :(. Is there any alternative way to achieve it? or At least download an excel file from dynamic internal table with header length till 60 char?

Comment: There are many workarounds: CSV file, OLE Excel, etc. But that's a completely different story. You will find a lot of information in SAP Community.

Comment: Thanks. For time being, have used SALV to create excel with data and Ole to open that excel and insert header data in 1st row.